# Outputting to a closed stream?

Tags: java

So I fixed my program but the problem is that after replacing all the blank spaces with tildes i have to output the text to a file that has been closed. How would I re-open the file for output and input something in?

```
//Name: Allen Li
//Program file: Vowels.Java 
//Purpose: Using File IO, read a file's input and output this text to a new text file
//When outputting, all blank spaces will be changed to tildes and there will be a count of each vowel(AEIOU)


import java.util.Scanner; //input
import java.io.File; //IO
import java.io.IOException; //IO exception class
import java.io.FileWriter; //file output
import java.io.FileReader; //file input
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; //if file isnt found, file not found class

public class Vowels { //class
 public static void main(String[] args) { //main method

  try { //try block
   FileReader poetry = new FileReader("poetry.txt"); 
   FileWriter dentist = new FileWriter( 
     "LI_ALLEN_dentist.txt"); 

   int a; 
   while ((a = poetry.read()) != -1) { 
    dentist.write(a); 
    System.out.print((char) a); //print the file to the monitor
   } 

   poetry.close(); 
   dentist.close(); 

   Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File( 
     "LI_ALLEN_dentist.txt")); 

   int numOfVowelsA = 0; //count #s of A/E/I/O/U vowels
   int numOfVowelsE = 0; 
   int numOfVowelsI = 0; 
   int numOfVowelsO = 0; 
   int numOfVowelsU = 0; 

   while (inFile.hasNext()) { 
    String sentence = inFile.next() /* ("\\S+") */; 

    for (int i = 0; i <= sentence.length() - 1; i++) { 
     if (sentence.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == 'a') { 
      numOfVowelsA++; 
     } 
     if (sentence.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == 'e') { 
      numOfVowelsE++; 
     } 
     if (sentence.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == 'i') { 
      numOfVowelsI++; 
     } 
     if (sentence.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == 'o') { 
      numOfVowelsO++; 
     } 
     if (sentence.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == 'u') { 
      numOfVowelsU++; 
     } 
    } 
   } 
   System.out.println(); 

   System.out.println("There are " + numOfVowelsA 
     + " A vowels in this file of text"); 
   System.out.println("There are " + numOfVowelsE 
     + " E vowels in this file of text."); 
   System.out.println("There are " + numOfVowelsI 
     + " I vowels in this file of text."); 
   System.out.println("There are " + numOfVowelsO 
     + " O vowels in this file of text."); 
   System.out.println("There are " + numOfVowelsU 
     + " U vowels in this file of text. "); 



   Scanner tildes = new Scanner(new File( 
     "LI_ALLEN_dentist.txt")); 
   while (tildes.hasNext()) { 
    String replace = tildes.nextLine(); 
    replace = replace.replaceAll(" ", "~"); 
    System.out.println(); 
    System.out.print(replace); 

   } 

  } catch (FileNotFoundException i) { 
   System.out.println("The file you are trying to use as input is not found. " + i); 
  } catch (IOException i) { 
   System.out.println("There is an issue with the input or output file. " + i); 
  } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just close the stream after filling it with the right values?

Comment: I've tried moving dentist.close(); to the end after the second while loop before the catch exceptions. For some reason, moving that line to the end somehow disabled the massive if block and the vowels in the lines don't count at all and all values end up as 0. @LuiggiMendoza

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close `inFile`. Close `inFile` first and then you are able to open it again in `tildes`.
Close it before `Scanner tildes = new Scanner(...);` line.

Comment: If I close inFile, that only allows it to evaluate and finish evaluating the lines of text on the file. Also if I have inFIle closed it doesn't evaluate the sentences.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say.. @allenlistar

Comment: If I close inFile it doesn't write anything to the file itself then there is no way to count the number of vowels.